# C# multiple events on a single button click?

Tags: c#, javascript, button

I'm new to C# have been learning it slowly for a couple of weeks and i know some basic JavaScript.

I wan't to make three buttons change the value of a string or int to different values at the different buttons, then start a common event that all buttons share. I know I can copy and paste them but I want to make the code short.

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string example = a;
   //Start the MainEvent
}
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string example = b;
   //Start the MainEvent
}
protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string example = c;
   //Start the MainEvent
}
protected void MainEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Content of MainEvent. Result of MainEvent is determined by the value of "Example".
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using only one event handler:

```
btn1.Click += MainEvent;
btn2.Click += MainEvent;
btn3.Click += MainEvent;

protected void MainEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string example;
    if(sender == btn1)
    {
        example = a
    }
    else if(sender == btn2)
    {
        example = b
    }
    else if(sender == btn3)
    {
        example = c
    }

    //Do whatever with example
}
```

Comment: The `is` operator is for type checking. You should use `==` or Object `ReferenceEquels`

Comment: This isn't really scalable, I agree with the common event but I'd think it would be better to make use of the `Tag` property

Comment: Or the `Name` property, if you think about it.

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with event handlers. but I think I see what it does.
But where am I supposed to place the top bit? the "btn1.click += MainEvent; "(...)

Comment: @Acnik at the constructor of the Form or at the Form_Load event handler.

You can also set the name of the handler through the form designer.

Comment: After i've now learned much more C# i see that this could be solved the way you've suggested or that I can write a function with a, b and c as input parameters :)